# How to center an ellipse into a frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment

How to center an ellipse into a frame ?

I've tried this but it wouldn't work :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[yshift=6.6cm,xshift=6.6cm,draw,ellipse,text width=2cm,align=center] 
  {Gerer poste de travail};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And, how please to draw this form :

[image]

Any better idea, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `\centering` inside the frame. And then the shifts are not needed.

Comment: @PaulGessler, I've tried to put `\centering{}` before that `\node`, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,ellipse,text width=2cm,align=center]   {Gerer poste de travail};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}`
Note: `\centering` does not take arguments.

Comment: @PaulGessler, Oh! thanks. But, in my frame I have many other tikz drawed objects in the same `\begin{tikzpicture}`, how to make that only make that ellipse in the center of the frame, please ?

Comment: Put `\centering` inside a group with the centered content (`{\centering <...your centered content...>}`) or use Herbert's answer below. But the `center` environment adds additional vertical space that may not be desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The little "person" is a `pic` path which can be reused as many times as desired. The `ellipse` is placed at `current page.center`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
Person/.pic={
  \begin{scope}[cyan]
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt] (phead) {};
  \draw (phead) -- coordinate[midway] (d) ++(0,-15pt) coordinate (c) -- ++(310:5pt);
  \draw (c) -- ++(230:5pt);
  \draw ([xshift=-5pt]d) -- ([xshift=5pt]d);
  \end{scope}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[
  draw,
  ellipse,
  text width=2cm,
  align=center
] 
  at (current page.center)
  (A)
  {Gerer poste de travail};
\foreach \Posicion in {{(-2,3)},{(3,2)},{([yshift=1cm]A.north)},{(-1,-3)}}
  \path pic at \Posicion {Person};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs two compilations.

Comment: Can you please help me [on this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178912/how-to-vertically-align-column-members) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `center` environment:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[yshift=6.6cm,xshift=6.6cm,draw,ellipse,text width=2cm,align=center] 
  {Gerer poste de travail};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

And your form is a simple drawing.

Comment: What about the second question, please?