# How to vertically align column members

Tags: vertical-alignment

How to make this all members of the last column get aligned vertically to top please?

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}   
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparatif entre Two Track Unified Process et Rational Unified Process}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|C{0.07\textwidth}*{4}{|C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}|}
\hline
& {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Axé développement} & {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Architecture logicielle} & {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Technologies} & {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Projets cibles} \\
\hline
RUP & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \[\geqslant 10p\] \\
\hline
2TUP & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} & \includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} &  \[*\]  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Small trip to improve your question. Have a look at the `demo` mode of the graphicx package to post your MWE as the code you pasted will not compile on our machines. Hint: you may just have to add `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inline equation form `\(...\)` in the last column, instead of `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass[french, demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}   
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparatif entre Two Track Unified Process et Rational Unified Process}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|C{0.07\textwidth}*{4}{|C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}|}
\hline
& {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Axé développement} & {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Architecture logicielle} & {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Technologies} & {\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont Projets cibles} \\
\hline
RUP & \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=1.8ex]{images/danger} & \(\geqslant 10p\) \\
\hline
2TUP & \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} & \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} & \includegraphics[width=4ex,height=1.8ex]{images/func_ok} &  \(*\)  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]