# How to draw a pic of a person with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would complete to my pic adding the draw of two people that are pushing a crate, like this figure or similar. How can you help me?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pattern[pattern=north east lines,thin] (0,0) rectangle (12,-.5    );
    \draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
    \draw[very thick] (3,0) rectangle +(6,3);
    \draw[very thick,blue,->] ($(8,1.5)+(1,0)$) -- +(2,0) node[very near end,below] {$\vec{F}$};
    \draw[very thick,red,->] ($(1,1.5)+(-.0,0)$)-- +(2,0) node[very near start,below] {$\vec{F}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would input the images of the little people into the tikzpicture, imho trying to recreate them with tikz is not worth the trouble.

Comment: Inkscape: trace and export. While it can be done, I would either just draw stickfigures, or `\includegraphics` as @Johannes_B suggests.

Comment: Are you unable to use the bitmap images because of copy restrictions? 
You can insert the image into tikzpicture as a background and then use that as a guide, making elements for each part of the human - e.g. one element for the hair, one for the head, etc - then remove the images.

Comment: I think that as for [aircraft](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847), tikz isn't up to the job and you need [picture mode](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AL82e.png)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177375/how-to-center-an-ellipse-into-a-frame, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/theory-of-mind-type-figure, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/add-an-exit-sign-running-person. There is also one somewhere showing how to include partial people for purposes of statistical representation. `tikzsymbols` may also be useful as it has stick figures with options for limb angles etc.

Comment: For the record, that is not a picture of two people pushing anything.

Comment: My english is weak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not as good as the [picture mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL82e.png) of @David Carlisle, but proudly done with tikz :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [line width=1cm, line cap=round, line join=round, rounded corners=4mm]
    % --- object ---
    \fill[red] (4,-10) rectangle +(11,15);
    \node[white,scale=30] at (9.5,-1){?};

    % pulling person
    \begin{scope}
      % --- body ---
      \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- ++(1,-4) coordinate (B);
      % --- legs ---
      \draw (B) -- ++(1,-3) -- ++(2,-3);
      \draw (B) -- ++(-1,-3) -- ++(2,-3);
      % --- arms ---
      \draw (A) -- ++(2,-1) -- ++(2,0);
      \draw (A) -- ++(2,-3) -- ++(2,0);
      % --- head ---
      \fill (A) ++(0,1.5) circle (1);
    \end{scope}

    % pushing person
    \begin{scope}[xshift=19cm]
      % --- body ---
      \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- ++(1,-4) coordinate (B);
      % --- legs ---
      \draw (B) -- ++(1,-3) -- ++(2,-3);
      \draw (B) -- ++(-1,-3) -- ++(2,-3);
      % --- arms ---
      \draw (A) -- ++(-2,-1) -- ++(-2,0);
      \draw (A) -- ++(-2,-3) -- ++(-2,0);
      % --- head ---
      \fill (A) ++(0,1.5) circle (1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]